# MVN WebApplication Template with Spring Securing + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am looking for a mvn project template that can be downloaded and used as a kick-off for a web application.

The requeriments are:

- Spring security (for user authentication and pages accesing control)
- Hibernate integration (for data persistance like users and more)
- The application must run on tomcat (i use TomEE)

I have a web application already running with pages and servlets and daos, persistence.xml and more. The problem is that i cant find the way to integrate this app with spring security, and for this reason i am looking for a project template...

Comment: Doubt there is such a thing. Are you using Spring MVC or some JSF technology? If it's the latter, google for how to do JSF with Spring Boot+Hibernate+Spring Security. 

If not, just google for the free version of dotCMS, maybe?

Comment: Ok thanks! I will look for dotCMS!

Answer (score 3):

Give [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) a shot. You can either use Spring Tool Suite or [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) site to get a secure web app running and using hibernate as ORM.

You can later choose to run the app in the embedded Tomcat/Jetty or package as WAR and deploy in container of your choice.